# In Log4j2.xml more than one different logs in same file but different location how we will do this?

Tags: log4j2

I am using log4j2.xml configuration file.
In my web application logs are different and location is different but file which keeps log is same so I want to add in same file , different logs from different location(different action) how we will do this?

Any one have idea Please help.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "location", do you mean location of log file?

Comment: I don't understand the question. "Same file but different location" doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: log4j creating two log files one is daily based and another one is month based problem is with month based log file it is creating new logs file but keeping all previous logs and current logs I want it should keep only current logs not all previous logs.

Comment: Ravindra - I don't mean to be rude but do you have someone with better English skills who can help you reword your question? We just can't understand what you are asking.